.NET MVC Azure Pipeline deployment - IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup not working as intended
I'm trying to deploy my .NET Framework MVC app to VM, using Azure Pipelines.
Relevant code:
- task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
            inputs:            
              IISDeploymentType: 'IISWebsite'
              ActionIISWebsite: 'CreateOrUpdateWebsite'
              WebsiteName: 'MySite'
              WebsitePhysicalPath: 'D:/MySite/WebUi'
              WebsitePhysicalPathAuth: 'WebsiteUserPassThrough'
              CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite: true
              AppPoolNameForWebsite: 'DefaultAppPool'
              DotNetVersionForWebsite: 'No Managed Code'
              PipeLineModeForWebsite: 'Integrated'
              AppPoolIdentityForWebsite: 'ApplicationPoolIdentity'
              AddBinding: true
              Bindings: |
                  {
                      bindings:[
                          {
                              "protocol":"http",
                              "ipAddress":"",
                              "hostname":"",
                              "port":"802",
                              "sslThumbprint":"",
                              "sniFlag":false
                          }
                      ]
                  }
          - task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
            inputs:
              WebSiteName: 'MySite'
              Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/WebUi/WebUi.zip'

The result is that in IIS Manager i can see that the new site has been created under the "Sites" folder, but when I press "Browse *:802 (http)", I'm getting default IIS 404 error (HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found),
with details:
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:802/
Physical Path      D:/MySite/WebUi
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

Although, when i changed this website App Pool from Unmanaged to v4.0, im getting standard web browser error:
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:802/
HTTP ERROR 404

not the detailed IIS error like when app pool is unmanaged.
The basic settings (like physical path) are fine, pointing to right place on drive, which contains folders: bin, Content, fonts, Scripts, Views, and files: favicon, global.asax, packages.config, web.config, so it looks fine.
What I've checked:

ASP.NET version, and other Windows Features on VM
Privileges to WebUi folder by IIS
Changing from DotNetVersionForWebsite: 'No Managed Code' to DotNetVersionForWebsite: 'v4.0' and changing App Pool to v4.0 does not make any difference.

This application was previously updated (on other VM) by just ctrl+c and ctrl+v contents of WebUi folder, so the application itself is OK.
The thing that I've discovered, is that on the VM where app is running fine, after going to base url (servername.internal.com for example) it's automatically redirecting to servername.internal.com/WebUi, and in my problematic case, it's not redirecting anywhere.
I don't know what else should i check. Maybe there is any way to dump IIS settings from other VM (where app is running fine) to compare it with the problematic VM IIS settings?

Please first try to manually setup of the site, then copy and paste the app contents to its physical path before integrating in pipelines. It would be helpful to rule out the cause by the IIS features on that server, the app itself or the deployment tool.
There is a chance that the site physical path is occupied by other processes on that server. You may have a test to reset IIS or take the app offline when during IIS deployment.
- powershell: |
    iisreset /noforce
  displayName: Reset IIS
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: 6

- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: 'MySite'
    Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/WebUi/WebUi.zip'
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: true


When i have done what You have proposed, i'm getting:
"Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated."
Which is fine i guess, because the page itself is properly deployed, and error is related to application, not the iis configuration? But still - i don't know, how to fix it in the pipeline.

I suggested manually setting up a site and then deploying the app contents. Do you mean your app didn't work that way?

I have done that, and the result is that im getting server error - it might be related to application itself (irrelevant), but the application itself is starting and is accessible via web browser.

If the manual deployment also incurred the server error, the issue was unlikely to be caused by the pipeline deployment tool. Can you share more details to reproduce the issue?

I have created default WebForms project via VS2019, then manually setup the site. Result is the same - 404 error, so i assume it's not related to the project itself, but to the VM configuration.. And i don't know what to check.

What if you create a sample hello-world app with VS and deploy it to the VM server?
